# add extended validation certificate to wampserver

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate

I have generated my certificate using:

```
openssl genrsa -out ca.key 2048
openssl req -new -x509 -key ca.key -out ca.crt
```

The certificates have been created.

How do I display the extended validation certificate when I access for example `"http://localhost/Web/"`

Also note that I am using WampServer

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

> I have generated mt certificated using [OpenSSL]...
>   How do I display the extended validation certificate when I access for example "http://localhost/Web/"

You can't because its not present.

First, OpenSSL generally conforms to the IETF's standards. There is no concept of extended validation.

Second, extended validation offers nothing by way of security (that is, there are no additional security controls to place that utilize it). EV is also known as ["PKI ME Harder"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate#PKI-Me-Harder). The [race to the bottom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_to_the_bottom) meant CAs had to stop validating regular certificates correctly because they could not maintain service on the declining profits. EV restores the profit levels and the validations that were always supposed to be occurring.

Third, the extended validation information is in the Cert Policy extension, and the IETF does not require it. See [OID for certificates issued under IETF policy?](http://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/pkix/current/msg33057.html) on the PKIX mailing list.

Fourth, extended validation is provided by the [CA/Browser Forums](https://cabforum.org/) in the [Extended Validation Guidelines](https://cabforum.org/extended-validation-2/).

Fifth, there is no one OID to cover extended validation. Each CA provides their own OID. See [Extended Validation certificate identification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate#Extended_Validation_certificate_identification).

Finally, OpenSSL does not issue certificates in accordance with the CA/BF EV Guidelines.

---

If a certificate includes the Cert Policy extension, then you can display it with the following. It prints all the information in a certificate:

```
openssl x509 -in server-cert.pem -text -noout
```